# I have excluded node_modules from MSBUILD, but it still traverses the directory and takes forever

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

At some point my project build started taking a long time. It's not a large project and it's directly related to the `node_modules` directory which is at the root of the project, and excluded from the project!

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefaultInstallExcludes>packages\**</DefaultInstallExcludes>
  <DefaultInstallExcludes>$(DefaultInstallExcludes);**\node_modules\**;node_modules\**</DefaultInstallExcludes> 
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>     
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.ascx" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.asmx" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.css" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.html" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.aspx" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\*.js" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
  <InstallInclude Include="**\images\**" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />      
</ItemGroup>
```

It seems it's excluding all the files properly, but it's still scanning the entire directory. How can I get it to completely ignore the `node_modules` folder entirely during a build? Tools version is 3.5. This used to take <30 seconds and at some point started taking ~10 minutes. VS Community 2019.

Comment: Did your project is a net framework web project?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT yes it is. Looking at your answer now :)

Comment: Any feedback will be expected and we are willing to help you further:)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT It's still taking a long time. I went a step further and marked the `node_modules` folder as a hidden folder and that didn't work either. This is a small project so this is very strange. It started happening recently and the node modules folder is the only culprit I can think of. I'll flat out delete the folder today to confirm

Comment: Actually, remove the `node modules` folder is what my answer did. And since you did not want the whole folder on the build process. For a better way, you should put the remove items on the top of the `proj` file. At least, before `InstallInclude`  item. Also, you could try to exclude `node_modules` folder on `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`. See update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `InstallInclude` is your custom item rather than the system item. And most of the files of `node_modules` are system items like `None` or `Content`.These are shown on the solution explorer and are scanned by msbuild.

The system build action are listed under [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019).

What you did is make the new `InstallInclude` item did not contain the files from `node_modules` and `packages`. But the system item which contains `node_modules` folder, so it will always scan the folder.

**Suggestion**

You should exclude that folder from system Item.

For new-sdk projects, `DefaultItemExcludes` does work but it does not work for net framework projects.

If your project target to `Net Framework`, you should use any system item remove to remove those files.

Use this:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Content Remove="node_modules\**" />
      <Compile Remove="node_modules\**" />
      <EmbeddedResource Remove="node_modules\**" />
      <None Remove="node_modules\**" />
      <Compile Remove=node_modules\**" />
      <TypeScriptCompile Remove="node_modules\**" />
    
    
      .... any system item
    
    </ItemGroup>



    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefaultInstallExcludes>packages\**</DefaultInstallExcludes>
      <DefaultInstallExcludes>$(DefaultInstallExcludes);**\node_modules\**;node_modules\**</DefaultInstallExcludes> 
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>     
      <InstallInclude Include="**\*.ascx" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
      <InstallInclude Include="**\*.asmx" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
      <InstallInclude Include="**\*.css" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
      <InstallInclude Include="**\*.html" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
      <InstallInclude Include="**\*.aspx" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
      <InstallInclude Include="**\*.js" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />
      <InstallInclude Include="**\images\**" Exclude="$(DefaultInstallExcludes)" />      
    </ItemGroup>
```

Exclude from tsconfig files:

modify `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ....
  },
  "include": [
   ...
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],

.....
}
```

modify `tsconfig.spec.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
   ....
  ],
  "include": [
    ....
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*"
  ]
  
}
```